# I have a thread.pool and how can i make Main Thread wait until all task are completed?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, threadpool

Hi i have the code below, i`m wondering how can i make Main Thread to wait until all task from thread pool are finished (I have a dynamic number of tasks, and 3 CPU cores max allocated). eg: i have 5 jobs to run the thread_pool can do 3 max in parallel.

```
{        
     for(i=0;i<n;i++)
     {

         TaskParams tp = new TaskParams(some params to be parsed to thread job);

         ScanAllSectors objAllSectors = new ScanAllSectors();//object containing job function

         ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(objAllSectors.vScan, tp);
     }
        //i want to block it here
    ...//some other functions that uses the result from the code above`
}
```

...so that`s why i want to block the main_thread until all jobs from threadpool are done, before the below functions to run.

Thanks!

Comment: Any reason to not use async / await and just wait using await `Task.WhenAll`?

Comment: [Parallel.ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992001(v=vs.110).aspx) and associated overloads, can specify max threads. life = easy

Comment: Thanks i`ll give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

Example of [Task Parallel Library (TPL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl)

```
Parallel.ForEach(
    ListOfStuff,
    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 },
    myStuffObj => DoAwesomeStuff(myStuffObj)
);

Console.WriteLine("All stuff done);
```

**Further reading**

[Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783747.aspx)

[ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism.aspx)